# How do I make my jQuery slides responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-slides

I'm working on a website for personal practice, and I've integrated a jQuery slide show for some photographs. My problem is that I can't figure out how to make these slides responsive when increasing and decreasing the screen size. I've checked what feels like everything but can't find the problem. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:400,400italic,500italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="sitemap" type="application/xml" title="Sitemap" href="sitemap.xml" />
  
     <style>
      /* Prevents slides from flashing */
      #slides {
        display:none;
      }
    </style>
  
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
 
  $(function(){
  
   var slideWidth = 700;
   var slideHeight = 393;
   
   if(window.innerWidth <= 400) {
    
    slideWidth = window.innerWidth;
   }
   
     $("#slides").slidesjs({
       play: {
         active: true,
           // [boolean] Generate the play and stop buttons.
           // You cannot use your own buttons. Sorry.
         effect: "fade",
           // [string] Can be either "slide" or "fade".
         interval: 3000,
           // [number] Time spent on each slide in milliseconds.
         auto: true,
           // [boolean] Start playing the slideshow on load.
         swap: true,
           // [boolean] show/hide stop and play buttons
         pauseOnHover: false,
           // [boolean] pause a playing slideshow on hover
         restartDelay: 2500
           // [number] restart delay on inactive slideshow
       },
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
     });
     
  });
  
  </script>
  
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <title>Viktor and Luise</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  
  <p class="HomeHeaderBig">Viktor & Luise</p>
  
  
  <!-- Menu -->
  
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="dropdown-button">Produkte</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html">Über uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="Impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <!-- Images -->
    <div id="slides">
      <img src="Images/VL-10.jpg" alt="throughtherackjacket">
      <img src="Images/VL-1.jpg" alt="storewindow">
      <img src="Images/VL-3.jpg" alt="whitejacket">
      <img src="Images/VL-4.jpg" alt="showcase1">
      <img src="Images/VL-5.jpg" alt="showcase2">
      <img src="Images/VL-6.jpg" alt="showcase3">
      <img src="Images/VL-7.jpg" alt="lvshoes">
      <img src="Images/VL-8.jpg" alt="polojacket">
      <img src="Images/VL-9.jpg" alt="shirt">
    </div>
  <script src="jquery.slides.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
 </body>
  

</html>
```

```html
img {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 4%;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

.slides {
 display: block;
 max-width: 50%;
 max-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 20%;
 margin-top: 2%
}

.slidesjs-container {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: red;

}
```

```html
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.1
(function() {

  (function($, window, document) {
    var Plugin, defaults, pluginName;
    pluginName = "slidesjs";
    defaults = {
      width: 1000,
      height: 900,
      start: 1,
      navigation: {
        active: true,
        effect: "slide"
      },
      pagination: {
        active: false,
        effect: "slide"
      },
      play: {
        active: false,
        effect: "slide",
        interval: 5000,
        auto: false,
        swap: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        restartDelay: 2500
      },
      effect: {
        slide: {
          speed: 500
        },
        fade: {
          speed: 300,
          crossfade: true
        }
      },
      callback: {
        loaded: function() {},
        start: function() {},
        complete: function() {}
      }
    };
    Plugin = (function() {

      function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
      }

      return Plugin;

    })();
    Plugin.prototype.init = function() {
      var $element, nextButton, pagination, playButton, prevButton, stopButton,
        _this = this;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      $.data(this, "animating", false);
      $.data(this, "total", $element.children().not(".slidesjs-navigation", $element).length);
      $.data(this, "current", this.options.start - 1);
      $.data(this, "vendorPrefix", this._getVendorPrefix());
      if (typeof TouchEvent !== "undefined") {
        $.data(this, "touch", true);
        this.options.effect.slide.speed = this.options.effect.slide.speed / 2;
      }
      $element.css({
      });
      $element.slidesContainer = $element.children().not(".slidesjs-navigation", $element).wrapAll("<div class='slidesjs-container'>", $element).parent().css({
        overflow: "hidden",
        position: "relative"
      });
      $(".slidesjs-container", $element).wrapInner("<div class='slidesjs-control'>", $element).children();
      $(".slidesjs-control", $element).css({
        position: "relative",
        left: 0
      });
      $(".slidesjs-control", $element).children().addClass("slidesjs-slide").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "100%",
        zIndex: 0,
        display: "none",
        webkitBackfaceVisibility: "hidden"
      });
      $.each($(".slidesjs-control", $element).children(), function(i) {
        var $slide;
        $slide = $(this);
        return $slide.attr("slidesjs-index", i);
      });
      if (this.data.touch) {
        $(".slidesjs-control", $element).on("touchstart", function(e) {
          return _this._touchstart(e);
        });
        $(".slidesjs-control", $element).on("touchmove", function(e) {
          return _this._touchmove(e);
        });
        $(".slidesjs-control", $element).on("touchend", function(e) {
          return _this._touchend(e);
        });
      }
      $element.fadeIn(0);
      this.update();
      if (this.data.touch) {
        this._setuptouch();
      }
      $(".slidesjs-control", $element).children(":eq(" + this.data.current + ")").eq(0).fadeIn(0, function() {
        return $(this).css({
          zIndex: 10
        });
      });
      if (this.options.navigation.active) {
        prevButton = $("<a>", {
          "class": "slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation",
          href: "#",
          title: "Previous",
          text: "<"
        }).appendTo($element);
        nextButton = $("<a>", {
          "class": "slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation",
          href: "#",
          title: "Next",
          text: ">"
        }).appendTo($element);
      }
      $(".slidesjs-next", $element).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _this.stop(true);
        return _this.next(_this.options.navigation.effect);
      });
      $(".slidesjs-previous", $element).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _this.stop(true);
        return _this.previous(_this.options.navigation.effect);
      });
      if (this.options.play.active) {
        playButton = $("<a>", {
          "class": "slidesjs-play slidesjs-navigation",
          href: "#",
          title: "Play",
          text: ""
        }).appendTo($element);
        stopButton = $("<a>", {
          "class": "slidesjs-stop slidesjs-navigation",
          href: "#",
          title: "Stop",
          text: ""
        }).appendTo($element);
        playButton.click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return _this.play(true);
        });
        stopButton.click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return _this.stop(true);
        });
        if (this.options.play.swap) {
          stopButton.css({
            display: "none"
          });
        }
      }
      if (this.options.pagination.active) {
        pagination = $("<ul>", {
          "class": "slidesjs-pagination"
        }).appendTo($element);
        $.each(new Array(this.data.total), function(i) {
          var paginationItem, paginationLink;
          paginationItem = $("<li>", {
            "class": "slidesjs-pagination-item"
          }).appendTo(pagination);
          paginationLink = $("<a>", {
            href: "#",
            "data-slidesjs-item": i,
            html: i + 1
          }).appendTo(paginationItem);
          return paginationLink.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            _this.stop(true);
            return _this.goto(($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-slidesjs-item") * 1) + 1);
          });
        });
      }
      $(window).bind("resize", function() {
        return _this.update();
      });
      this._setActive();
      if (this.options.play.auto) {
        this.play();
      }
      return this.options.callback.loaded(this.options.start);
    };
    Plugin.prototype._setActive = function(number) {
      var $element, current;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      current = number > -1 ? number : this.data.current;
      $(".active", $element).removeClass("active");
      return $(".slidesjs-pagination li:eq(" + current + ") a", $element).addClass("active");
    };
    Plugin.prototype.update = function() {
      var $element, height, width;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      $(".slidesjs-control", $element).children(":not(:eq(" + this.data.current + "))").css({
        display: "none",
        left: 0,
        zIndex: 0
      });
      width = 1000;
      height = 900;
      this.options.width = width;
      this.options.height = height;
      return $(".slidesjs-control, .slidesjs-container", $element).css({
        width: width,
        height: height
      });
    };
    Plugin.prototype.next = function(effect) {
      var $element;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      $.data(this, "direction", "next");
      if (effect === void 0) {
        effect = this.options.navigation.effect;
      }
      if (effect === "fade") {
        return this._fade();
      } else {
        return this._slide();
      }
    };
    Plugin.prototype.previous = function(effect) {
      var $element;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      $.data(this, "direction", "previous");
      if (effect === void 0) {
        effect = this.options.navigation.effect;
      }
      if (effect === "fade") {
        return this._fade();
      } else {
        return this._slide();
      }
    };
    Plugin.prototype.goto = function(number) {
      var $element, effect;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      if (effect === void 0) {
        effect = this.options.pagination.effect;
      }
      if (number > this.data.total) {
        number = this.data.total;
      } else if (number < 1) {
        number = 1;
      }
      if (typeof number === "number") {
        if (effect === "fade") {
          return this._fade(number);
        } else {
          return this._slide(number);
        }
      } else if (typeof number === "string") {
        if (number === "first") {
          if (effect === "fade") {
            return this._fade(0);
          } else {
            return this._slide(0);
          }
        } else if (number === "last") {
          if (effect === "fade") {
            return this._fade(this.data.total);
          } else {
            return this._slide(this.data.total);
          }
        }
      }
    };
    Plugin.prototype._setuptouch = function() {
      var $element, next, previous, slidesControl;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      slidesControl = $(".slidesjs-control", $element);
      next = this.data.current + 1;
      previous = this.data.current - 1;
      if (previous < 0) {
        previous = this.data.total - 1;
      }
      if (next > this.data.total - 1) {
        next = 0;
      }
      slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
        display: "block",
        left: this.options.width
      });
      return slidesControl.children(":eq(" + previous + ")").css({
        display: "block",
        left: -this.options.width
      });
    };
    Plugin.prototype._touchstart = function(e) {
      var $element, touches;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      touches = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
      this._setuptouch();
      $.data(this, "touchtimer", Number(new Date()));
      $.data(this, "touchstartx", touches.pageX);
      $.data(this, "touchstarty", touches.pageY);
      return e.stopPropagation();
    };
    Plugin.prototype._touchend = function(e) {
      var $element, duration, prefix, slidesControl, timing, touches, transform,
        _this = this;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      touches = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
      slidesControl = $(".slidesjs-control", $element);
      if (slidesControl.position().left > this.options.width * 0.5 || slidesControl.position().left > this.options.width * 0.1 && (Number(new Date()) - this.data.touchtimer < 250)) {
        $.data(this, "direction", "previous");
        this._slide();
      } else if (slidesControl.position().left < -(this.options.width * 0.5) || slidesControl.position().left < -(this.options.width * 0.1) && (Number(new Date()) - this.data.touchtimer < 250)) {
        $.data(this, "direction", "next");
        this._slide();
      } else {
        prefix = this.data.vendorPrefix;
        transform = prefix + "Transform";
        duration = prefix + "TransitionDuration";
        timing = prefix + "TransitionTimingFunction";
        slidesControl[0].style[transform] = "translateX(0px)";
        slidesControl[0].style[duration] = this.options.effect.slide.speed * 0.85 + "ms";
      }
      slidesControl.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", function() {
        prefix = _this.data.vendorPrefix;
        transform = prefix + "Transform";
        duration = prefix + "TransitionDuration";
        timing = prefix + "TransitionTimingFunction";
        slidesControl[0].style[transform] = "";
        slidesControl[0].style[duration] = "";
        return slidesControl[0].style[timing] = "";
      });
      return e.stopPropagation();
    };
    Plugin.prototype._touchmove = function(e) {
      var $element, prefix, slidesControl, touches, transform;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      touches = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
      prefix = this.data.vendorPrefix;
      slidesControl = $(".slidesjs-control", $element);
      transform = prefix + "Transform";
      $.data(this, "scrolling", Math.abs(touches.pageX - this.data.touchstartx) < Math.abs(touches.pageY - this.data.touchstarty));
      if (!this.data.animating && !this.data.scrolling) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this._setuptouch();
        slidesControl[0].style[transform] = "translateX(" + (touches.pageX - this.data.touchstartx) + "px)";
      }
      return e.stopPropagation();
    };
    Plugin.prototype.play = function(next) {
      var $element, currentSlide, slidesContainer,
        _this = this;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      if (!this.data.playInterval) {
        if (next) {
          currentSlide = this.data.current;
          this.data.direction = "next";
          if (this.options.play.effect === "fade") {
            this._fade();
          } else {
            this._slide();
          }
        }
        $.data(this, "playInterval", setInterval((function() {
          currentSlide = _this.data.current;
          _this.data.direction = "next";
          if (_this.options.play.effect === "fade") {
            return _this._fade();
          } else {
            return _this._slide();
          }
        }), this.options.play.interval));
        slidesContainer = $(".slidesjs-container", $element);
        if (this.options.play.pauseOnHover) {
          slidesContainer.unbind();
          slidesContainer.bind("mouseenter", function() {
            return _this.stop();
          });
          slidesContainer.bind("mouseleave", function() {
            if (_this.options.play.restartDelay) {
              return $.data(_this, "restartDelay", setTimeout((function() {
                return _this.play(true);
              }), _this.options.play.restartDelay));
            } else {
              return _this.play();
            }
          });
        }
        $.data(this, "playing", true);
        $(".slidesjs-play", $element).addClass("slidesjs-playing");
        if (this.options.play.swap) {
          $(".slidesjs-play", $element).hide();
          return $(".slidesjs-stop", $element).show();
        }
      }
    };
    Plugin.prototype.stop = function(clicked) {
      var $element;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      clearInterval(this.data.playInterval);
      if (this.options.play.pauseOnHover && clicked) {
        $(".slidesjs-container", $element).unbind();
      }
      $.data(this, "playInterval", null);
      $.data(this, "playing", false);
      $(".slidesjs-play", $element).removeClass("slidesjs-playing");
      if (this.options.play.swap) {
        $(".slidesjs-stop", $element).hide();
        return $(".slidesjs-play", $element).show();
      }
    };
    Plugin.prototype._slide = function(number) {
      var $element, currentSlide, direction, duration, next, prefix, slidesControl, timing, transform, value,
        _this = this;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      if (!this.data.animating && number !== this.data.current + 1) {
        $.data(this, "animating", true);
        currentSlide = this.data.current;
        if (number > -1) {
          number = number - 1;
          value = number > currentSlide ? 1 : -1;
          direction = number > currentSlide ? -this.options.width : this.options.width;
          next = number;
        } else {
          value = this.data.direction === "next" ? 1 : -1;
          direction = this.data.direction === "next" ? -this.options.width : this.options.width;
          next = currentSlide + value;
        }
        if (next === -1) {
          next = this.data.total - 1;
        }
        if (next === this.data.total) {
          next = 0;
        }
        this._setActive(next);
        slidesControl = $(".slidesjs-control", $element);
        if (number > -1) {
          slidesControl.children(":not(:eq(" + currentSlide + "))").css({
            display: "none",
            left: 0,
            zIndex: 0
          });
        }
        slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
          display: "block",
          left: value * this.options.width,
          zIndex: 10
        });
        this.options.callback.start(currentSlide + 1);
        if (this.data.vendorPrefix) {
          prefix = this.data.vendorPrefix;
          transform = prefix + "Transform";
          duration = prefix + "TransitionDuration";
          timing = prefix + "TransitionTimingFunction";
          slidesControl[0].style[transform] = "translateX(" + direction + "px)";
          slidesControl[0].style[duration] = this.options.effect.slide.speed + "ms";
          return slidesControl.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", function() {
            slidesControl[0].style[transform] = "";
            slidesControl[0].style[duration] = "";
            slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
              left: 0
            });
            slidesControl.children(":eq(" + currentSlide + ")").css({
              display: "none",
              left: 0,
              zIndex: 0
            });
            $.data(_this, "current", next);
            $.data(_this, "animating", false);
            slidesControl.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd");
            slidesControl.children(":not(:eq(" + next + "))").css({
              display: "none",
              left: 0,
              zIndex: 0
            });
            if (_this.data.touch) {
              _this._setuptouch();
            }
            return _this.options.callback.complete(next + 1);
          });
        } else {
          return slidesControl.stop().animate({
            left: direction
          }, this.options.effect.slide.speed, (function() {
            slidesControl.css({
              left: 0
            });
            slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
              left: 0
            });
            return slidesControl.children(":eq(" + currentSlide + ")").css({
              display: "none",
              left: 0,
              zIndex: 0
            }, $.data(_this, "current", next), $.data(_this, "animating", false), _this.options.callback.complete(next + 1));
          }));
        }
      }
    };
    Plugin.prototype._fade = function(number) {
      var $element, currentSlide, next, slidesControl, value,
        _this = this;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      if (!this.data.animating && number !== this.data.current + 1) {
        $.data(this, "animating", true);
        currentSlide = this.data.current;
        if (number) {
          number = number - 1;
          value = number > currentSlide ? 1 : -1;
          next = number;
        } else {
          value = this.data.direction === "next" ? 1 : -1;
          next = currentSlide + value;
        }
        if (next === -1) {
          next = this.data.total - 1;
        }
        if (next === this.data.total) {
          next = 0;
        }
        this._setActive(next);
        slidesControl = $(".slidesjs-control", $element);
        slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
          display: "none",
          left: 0,
          zIndex: 10
        });
        this.options.callback.start(currentSlide + 1);
        if (this.options.effect.fade.crossfade) {
          slidesControl.children(":eq(" + this.data.current + ")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed);
          return slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").stop().fadeIn(this.options.effect.fade.speed, (function() {
            slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
              zIndex: 0
            });
            $.data(_this, "animating", false);
            $.data(_this, "current", next);
            return _this.options.callback.complete(next + 1);
          }));
        } else {
          return slidesControl.children(":eq(" + currentSlide + ")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed, (function() {
            slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").stop().fadeIn(_this.options.effect.fade.speed, (function() {
              return slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
                zIndex: 10
              });
            }));
            $.data(_this, "animating", false);
            $.data(_this, "current", next);
            return _this.options.callback.complete(next + 1);
          }));
        }
      }
    };
    Plugin.prototype._getVendorPrefix = function() {
      var body, i, style, transition, vendor;
      body = document.body || document.documentElement;
      style = body.style;
      transition = "transition";
      vendor = ["Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml", "O", "ms"];
      transition = transition.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + transition.substr(1);
      i = 0;
      while (i < vendor.length) {
        if (typeof style[vendor[i] + transition] === "string") {
          return vendor[i];
        }
        i++;
      }
      return false;
    };
    return $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
      return this.each(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
          return $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
        }
      });
    };
  })(jQuery, window, document);

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Work on removing width from your slide configurations. i.e `slideWidth = 700`

Comment: Checkout [this demo](http://jsbin.com/tufuniligo). It is responsive. It is your code without [tag:css]

Comment: After I remove the widths, the entire slideshow and pictures disappear.

Comment: Just check the demo and try to built on it.

Comment: Ok, so in the jquery it has `Plugin.prototype.update = function() {
      var $element, height, width;
      $element = $(this.element);
      this.data = $.data(this);
      $(".slidesjs-control", $element).children(":not(:eq(" + this.data.current + "))").css({
        display: "none",
        left: 0,
        zIndex: 0
      });
      width = 1000;
      height = 900;
  ... `           does anyone know how I could change this to make it responsive? % signs don't work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive

see it in this link: http://getbootstrap.com/

use @media tags for define mobile view, desktop view, tablet view, landscape view, etc, example here http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

> see...you can either refer bootstrap...its a best framework for
>   responsive websites and i think img-responsive class can slove your
>   problem some extent,and note that please remove inline width while
>   using responsive framework

Comment: Ok, so in the jquery it has Plugin.prototype.update = function() { var $element, height, width; $element = $(this.element); this.data = $.data(this); $(".slidesjs-control", $element).children(":not(:eq(" + this.data.current + "))").css({ display: "none", left: 0, zIndex: 0 }); width = 1000; height = 900; ... does anyone know how I could change this to make it responsive? % signs don't work. Thanks for the help! –

Answer (score 0):

Making an slide responsive may get you in some trouble, specially if you are doing it with jQuery. In my opinion, you'd need to make a couple of things:

1. The most straightforward is using media-queries, percentages and stuff like that to make the slide adapt to diferent screen sizes.
2. And most important, you have to say goodbye to jQuery, as it has a really bad performance on mobile devices (you may not sense it on an iPhone, but surelly will in all lower and medium devices). You must create a function similar to jQuery animate but using the css3 transitions, that are hardware acelerated and much more efficient.

If you do this, the slide will work great even in the slowest devices.